# Formula of Heat Generated by Continuous or Acute Force Exertion on Elastic Object

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, thermodynamics, elasticity, stress-strain

See the figure below. Ignoring friction but not elasticity, I am assuming the object will be deformed and heat up by part of the energy transferred by F. What does the general formula to demonstrate this look like?

[image]

Comment: With perfect elasticity there is no loss. The actual lossiness is a property of both material and the size of deformation (and possibly of speed of deformation), so there is no general answer with going into the lab (or a tabulation) to find some parameters.

Comment: Intuition says there should be something straightforward for plastic deformation that fits with Hooke's Law to explain lossiness though